# Cocos2d Screen capture and get sprite from UIImage

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uiimage, screen, sprite, capture

I'm very headache about this problem, I'm using these code for capturing a part of the screen

```
-(UIImage *) glToUIImage {

    userphotoCount++;
    [CCDirector sharedDirector].nextDeltaTimeZero = YES;

    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    CCLayerColor* whitePage = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(255, 255, 255, 0) width:winSize.width height:winSize.height];
    whitePage.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);

    CCRenderTexture* rtx = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:815 height:532];
    [rtx begin];
    [whitePage visit];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] visit];
    [rtx end];

    return [rtx getUIImageFromBuffer];

}
```

I can get my UIImage by

```
image = [self glToUIImage];
```

Then I try to use this code to generate a sprite by the UIImage

```
-(void) ImageSprite{

image = [self glToUIImage];
userAns =  [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:image.CGImage key:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"photoCap%d.png", userphotoCount]];
    userAns.position=ccp(780,410);
    userAns.scale=0.6;
        [self addChild:userAns z:20];
}
```

I can get image by these code at first time, but after I changed the screen's contents and use these code to generate new sprite(new UIImage) with the new contents, I'm failed.... the image doesn't change to new image...

How can I get the new image sprite when every time I run the "imageSprite" code?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the new image sprite, but you must to change key

[CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:image.CGImage key:**key**];

Comment: I try to use

[NSString stringWithFormat:@"photoCap%d.png", userphotoCount]

as the key, so when running 

-(UIImage *) glToUIImage

the "userphotoCount++" can give a new number for photoCap%d.png

Do you mean it's wrong? can you give me some suggestions?

My purpose is:

when everytime user tap a button, he can get the new sprite with new image